# Creating Arrays from a plist file in iphone SDK 3.3 and up : objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multidimensional-array, plist

I have run into this issue and have put some major time into finding the answer. I am somewhat new to objective c but not to programming.

Here is my question.

I have a plist file with this structure

```
root {
  A (
       {songTitle : contents of song},
       {songTitle : contents of song}
  ),
  B (
       {songTitle : contents of song}
  ),
  C (
       {songTitle : contents of song}
  ),
... kepps going
}
```

Sorry if the the plist structure is not correct.

Pretty much I have a root dictionary (that is what it comes with) that contains an array of A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,...Z (alphabet)

Each letter of the alphabet array contains 1 or more dictionaries that have a key, value pair of songTitle (this could be any string) as the key and the song lyrics for the value.

My issue here is I need to create an array of all song titles and have been having a rough time trying to find out how to do this. I own 4 books on object c and none of them go into detail about multidimensional arrays and how to access pieces inside them.

I have created an array with all the letters and have created an array that contains the objects from each letter.

Like I stated before I need to find out how to make an array that contains each song title.

If you can help me that would save me a lot of time.

Thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 0):

If you have single array with the contents of all the letters, the rest is fairly simple. Iterate through the objects and call the dictionary method `allKeys` on each one. Each call to `allKeys` will return an NSArray containing the keys of that specific dictionary, which you can then place into another array.

#### EDIT

I made a mistake, didn't go deep enough. This is what I would do:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; //not using alloc and init means this isn't retained, so it will be autoreleased at the end of the method
NSArray *allLetterContents = [plistDict allValues]; // array of arrays, where each element is the content of a 'letter' in your plist (i.e. each element is an array of dictionaries)

NSMutableArray *allSongTitles = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(NSArray *oneLetterContents in allLetterContents)
{
    for(NSDictionary *song in oneLetterContents)
    {
        [allSongTitles addObject:[song objectForKey:@"songTitle"]]
    }
}

return allSongTitles;
```

This array isn't guaranteed to be sorted alphabetically, so you'll have to call [sortedArrayUsingSelector:] on it.

Reference:
[NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:)
[NSDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are suggesting I change my root from a dictionary to an array?

Maybe it might be better to show my code here.
Also I have attached an updated version of my plist file

Sorry seems I cannot add the image here but you can view it 
http://www.wesduff.com/images/forum_images/plist_examp.png

So as you can see I have updated the plist file to show the array of letters that each contain multiple dictionaries. Each dictionary has a songTitle and a songLyrics.

How can I write code to get an array of songTitles.

Here is what I have come up with so far

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
//This gives me an array of all the letters in alphabetical order
NSArray *array = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

/** 
Now I need to find out how to get an array of all songTitles
**/
```

I am still working on this and looking through what others have written but have not found anything yet.

As the first answer has suggested, should I change the root to an array or keep it as I have it in this plist image I have attached.

Thanks again,

Wes

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some more digging and came up with this from the plist file that was included in this picture

http://www.wesduff.com/images/forum_images/plist_examp.png

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//path for plist file
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"songList" ofType:@"plist"];

//dictionary created from plist file
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

//release the path because it is no longer needed
[path release];

//temp array to hold an array of all alphabetical letters
NSArray *array = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
//assign array to allLetters array
self.allLetters = array;

//Create two mutable arrays for the songArray (could do a little cleaner job of this here)
NSMutableArray *songArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *songTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Add messy array to songArray then we can work with the songArray (maybe something better to do here)
for(id key in dict)
{
    [songArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:key]];
}

//temp array to hold a messy array for all of the songTitles
NSArray *tempArray = [songArray valueForKey:@"songTitle"];

//go through the temparray and clean it up to make one array of all song titles and sort them
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [tempArray count]; i++) {
    [songTitles addObjectsFromArray:[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
}

//assign all song titles to our array of songTitles
self.allSongTitles = songTitles;

[dict release];
[allSongTitles release];
[songArray release];
[tempArray release];
[array release];
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

}

I am sure there is probably a better way to do this but this is what I have come up with on my own. Thanks

Comment: I'll have an edited answer up soon, but I'd like to point something out first. See that first loop, `for(id key in dict)`? The variable you called `key` is misnamed, it's not iterating through the keys of the dictionary, but the values. If you changed the loop to read `for(id key in [dict allKeys])`, then it would be iterating over the set of keys. On a side note, when you add information to a question, please edit the original question. This isn't a forum, anything beneath the question should be an answer attempt. If you need to, leave a comment under someone else's answer.

Comment: @Endemic: You are WRONG. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW2 Section Adopting Fast Enumeration: "NSDictionary enumerates its keys"